# ASP.Net Ajax Photo Upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, ajax

I have a modal that I implemented using the jQuery Colorbox and the modal works great for everything. However I have to have the functionality of an 'Update Your Picture' Member picture area and I wanted to acheive this through AJAX. Apparently this is possible but not really through AJAX. I have tried to implement the AJAX Upload function using this guy's method

[AJAX Upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/)

but am not being sucessful, I am starting to think that it is because I load the functionality into the DOM later on (because of the modal). Does anyone have any method and examples for doing a photo upload done with javascript(jQuery preferably) and ASP.Net (C#). It would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Similar question and a solution :

[Image Upload Preview in Update Panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803502/image-upload-preview-in-update-panel/)

Direct link to sample application [here](http://pokein.codeplex.com/releases/view/54534)

Answer (score 1):

I always use iframes to do any types of upload...you can show/hide your iframe with javascript and the c# page in the iframe can handle any type of database updating you need...let me know if you want an example...

Comment: you should avoid iframes as much as possible. Instead use updatepanel (part of ajaxcontroltoolkit).

Comment: why should you avoid iframes?

Comment: @waqasahmed An updatepanel is not going to do an ajax file upload.  Only an iframe will.  An iframe is a perfectly fine solution in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you think that your problem is because you *"load the functionality into the DOM later on"*
you should try to use the [jQuery live event](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) (new in 1.3) or the [LiveQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery)